# Using m2mqtt paho c# client library to connect to azure

Tags: .net, azure, compact-framework, mqtt, windows-embedded-compact

Im using m2mqtt c# client library to connect to azure. While the connection to azure from my laptop using the .NET framework has been successfully established but when I try to connect to azure using WinCE 2013 with .Net 3.9 Compact Framework Im getting errors on Toradex SoM Colibri VF50. I have used the dll as mentioned in the library for .net compact framework but still getting errors.I have used the same code for both purposes but still didnt succeed. The error while debugging is

```
Exception handle:Libraries compiled without SSL Support.
```

When building the code there are no errors.
When I try to run the code using break points I realised that the SSL symbol is not being enabled . As mentioned in their readme file they say that the symbol SSL is by default enabled. But over .net compact framework it isnt working. If anyone has worked or has some link please share....

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at [the CF 3.9 project file on github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/blob/master/M2Mqtt/M2Mqtt.NetCf39.csproj), it doesn't look like SSL is defined like it is for some of the other csproj files. You'll probably have to add that and recompile the library for CF 3.9. If you compare the DefineConstants tag on the various projects you'll see where it should go.